# Cannot deploy smart contracts on mainnet "contract creation code storage out of gas"

Tags: remix, ether

I have created a simple arbitrage smart contract, which I am unable to deploy on the mainnet. I even tried the basic ERC-20 Contract but still it gave me the same error.

Comment: Can you share the contract code

Comment: `// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {}

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}`

Comment: This is the basic erc20 code